# Ionic Modal Parameter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

My Modal Code here

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```

My Button and Function code Here (button in modal)

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate" ng-repeat='i in rate_num' ng-click='rateStar(i)'></button>//rate_num = [1,2,3,4,5];

$scope.rateStar = function(n){
      console.log(n);
      $rootScope.rate = n;
    };
```

it works fine no modal.
butin modal it is not working.

when i click that button i want to console.log(Number);
ex) when i click first button, i want to console.log(1), after click second -> console.log(2).. and so on

but now that code run only console.log(1) -> only first element called... where is wrong...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

index.html :

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ModalDemoController">
        <button ng-click="showModal()">Show</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
  <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="dark">
      <h1 class="title">Modal Demo</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear ion-close" ng-click="closeModal()"></button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="content-stable">
        <button  ng-repeat='i in rate_num' class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"  ng-click='rateStar(i)'> {{i}}</button>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

and Controller:

```
.controller('ModalDemoController', function($scope,$ionicModal) {

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.rate_num = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope.showModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };    
    $scope.rateStar = function(n){
      console.log(n);
      $scope.rate = n;
    };
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What a Nice Guy , Thanks!

Comment: guys, i have a question. why my code not works, and your code works? can you explain it?